# Why is Ant using Velocity 1.4 when I copy an 1.7 version into the Ant lib folder?

Tags: java, ant, velocity

I have a project which I build with Ant. My problem is that it needs Velocity in order to build properly but when I copy Velocity into the ant lib folder (1.7) I can see in the Velocity log that it uses `1.4` for some reason:

> Tue May 03 10:16:29 CEST 2016   [info] Starting Jakarta Velocity v1.4

How is this possible? I checked the `MANIFEST` file and the version I copy to Ant is indeed `1.7`. If I delete it the Ant build fails so I'm sure that this .jar is being used but in the `velocity.log` file I see that Velocity `1.4` boots up. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try running `ant` with the `-diagnostics` option? It gives you some insight in which jars are loaded.

Comment: No I used the `-debug` option and there is only the `1.7` .jar on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity version above 1.4 rebranded from "Jakarta Velocity" to "Apache Velocity". Code snippets: [1.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/velocity/velocity-dep/1.4/org/apache/velocity/runtime/RuntimeInstance.java#RuntimeInstance.init%28%29), [1.6.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.6.4/org/apache/velocity/runtime/RuntimeInstance.java#RuntimeInstance.init%28%29), [1.7](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.velocity/velocity/1.7/org/apache/velocity/runtime/RuntimeInstance.java#RuntimeInstance.init%28%29)

Clearly you have Velocity 1.4 in classpath even though there is 1.7 in classpath as well.

Answering more generic question:
"Why version x.y is used if version x.z should be used instead?"

*Solution #1* (runtime)

- Get id of your java process: `jps -v`
- Get classpath (and other info): `jinfo $pid`
- Look for multiple velocity jars. Very likely velocity 1.4 will be in front of 1.7

*Solution #2* (offline, given you are looking for `RuntimeInstance` class)

- Navigate to your ant distribution
- Run `for i in **/*.jar; do jar -tvf "$i" | grep -Hsi RuntimeInstance && echo "$i"; done` command which will look through all jars for given class name. This helps in case if velocity was packaged inside another jar (instead of being present as separate artefact)

Of course there few other ways how you can see different versions - maybe you patching wrong distribution of ant, maybe your velocity sneaked somewhere in system classpath. However combination of two above should highlight root cause of version mismatch.